# Conveying 'future me'

Tags: traduction, anglais, néologismes

Happy New Year to everyone!

The term "future me" typically refers to oneself at some point in the future, as opposed to the current version of oneself. It's a way of thinking about your future self, often used when making decisions or plans that will affect you at a later time. Considering "future me" involves anticipating how your actions today might impact your well-being, goals, or circumstances in the future. It's a way of encouraging a sense of responsibility and consideration for the consequences of present actions on your future self.

How can one convey 'future me' in French? Can 'le moi futur' or 'le moi dans le futur' be used?

Comment: I don't have a proper answer, but all the answers currently sound like literal translations to me. Maybe it's because I met the English idiom before the French translation that I feel this way, but I'd say a French speaker would rather talk about more general concepts to convey that idea, like "l'avenir", where you generally implicitly include yourself and yours.

Comment: @Kaiido yes, the phrase is way less common in French than English except maybe when the conversation involves time travel. For some reason, we prefer the less schizophrenic "Je [1st person verb] *dans le futur*".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

J'ai toujours vu/lu "*le moi du futur*", en particulier dans les memes, blagues sur internet etc. Ça donne un côté un peu "blague" donc c'est peut-être pas la formulation la plus "noble" mais c'est celle que je rencontre le plus.

[Exemple](https://www.reddit.com/r/penseesdedouche/comments/18ve14k/vous_%C3%AAtes_constamment_observ%C3%A9s_par_votre_moi_du/) :

> Vous êtes constamment observés par votre "moi" du futur, à travers les souvenirs.
>
> *Pour le contexte, provient du subreddit français équivalent à son homologue anglophone "Shower Thoughts", consacré au genre de réflexions étranges qu'on a typiquement dans la douche.*

Answer (score 3):

> Mon futur moi.

On le trouve aussi dans un [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=futur%20moi%2Cmoi%20du%20futur%2Cmoi%20dans%20le%20futur%2Cmon%20futur%20moi&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3). Est-ce un calque ? Je ne sais pas mais j'aime bien.

Answer (score 3):

Il m'arrive de dire ou d'entendre **Moi dans six mois** ou bien **Moi dans dix ans**, en précisant de quel futur il s'agit.

Answer (score 2):

I would use ***moi dans le futur*** (without article) to convey the idea of '**future me**' or '**my future self**'.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the French language doesn't use the verb "future," but rather the adjective or noun! For example, the equivalent of conveying "future me" in French is "Mon futur."

Comment: Merci de votre réponse. Bonne année et soyez bienvenue chez FSE. J'ai corrigé quelques fautes de frappe.

Comment: @Candide The word _future_ is never used as a verb, to my knowledge. It certainly isn't a verb in the expression “future me”.

Comment: @Segorian , thank you !

Comment: The future I talked about is the context explained in the question.